# Hardware inspired loop. Nonsense?

Tags: c, performance, loops, embedded, verilog

The other day I've learnt a cool trick in Verilog. When you need to do something repeatedly. You could use a shift register to count the number of incrementation. Just shifting a 1 from LSB to MSB, and when it reach the MSB you're done.

In C it would be something like this:

```
for(j=0b1; !(j & (1<<16)); j=j<<1)
{
/*do a thing 16 times*/
}
```

I know it has limited use because of the bit width, but it isn't involving any addition so it is fast.
So my question: **Is there any use of this? Is it worth it to use in C or any other high-level language?**

Maybe in embedded systems where resources are limited.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that addition is slower than shifting?  It certainly isn't on any modern cpu, not even embedded cores.  Nor is the bit test.  So yes, nonsense.

Comment: interesting but i don't see much cpu cycle gain here. !

Comment: @HansPassant I thought an adder mechanism is need more resource than rearranging some wires. And when I used this technique on a FPGA I gained some floor space. But then I used 2048 bit wide registers.

Comment: Well if you design a processor where shift isn't only faster than addition but this speed difference is actually exposed (ie shift actually takes fewer cycles than add, instead of wasting some time), then you could make it worth it. I haven't heard of any such processors existing (yet), maybe it'll become a thing when registers become wider and the speed difference between shift and add becomes bigger.

Comment: Shifting used to be faster than multiplication on very old architectures. It only makes sense in Verilog since shifters are implemented with fewer gates than adders. And it really doesn't make sense on CISCs like x86 which has the `LOOP` family instructions.

Comment: This is called one-hot encoding.

Comment: Clarification question: Are you asking about whether this is worth it in Verilog hardware design, or whether it's worth it in C software design?  Please edit to clarify that....

Comment: Don't down-vote a question like this. Don't discourage an inquiring mind.

Comment: @Adam12 Just googled that and found this http://www.vlsi-world.com/content/view/42/34/. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it isn't involving any addition so it is fast

For which CPU architecture is shift faster than addition? Also, what makes you think the compiler for that specific architecture wouldn't do the optimization from addition to shift automatically, if it would turn out that shift is faster?

> Is there any use of this?

For optimization purposes, no there isn't any use of it.

For other purposes, yes, code like that is commonly used for masking out individual bits of a byte. I believe the two most common approaches are these:

```
uint8_t mask; 

for(mask = 0x01; mask != 0x00; mask<<=1)
{
  do_something (data & mask);
}
```

or

```
for(i=0; i<8; i++)
{
  do_something (data & (1<<i));
}
```

Comment: The only thing that's made me think the shift is more efficient than adding is Verilog where by default + is invoking a 32bit adder, while << is just a reordering of wires.                            So this code can be used for iterating through a PORT of a microcontroller bit by bit? Read a pin do something with the reading then move to the next one.

Comment: @Stiggo Yes, a port, a flag register, a part of a data protocol, some eeprom settings variable etc etc.

Answer (score 8):

This is very **not** worth it. It make the code much less cleaner and harder to read, and the performance difference it negligible.

Your compiler can do these types of optimizations much better than you can. Short loops like this might even be unrolled for performance reasons. However, if you write the loop like that a compiler might not be able to figure that out as easily, so you might even be slowing the program down.

This is really a case of micro-optimization that will almost certainly never make a noticeable difference on your program's runtime.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that most of the guys commenting / answering does not really understand what asker is talking about. Verilog language is for hardware design and hardware design is very different thing than software design, no CPU cycles or anything like that. However, short answer is still: No. Long answer:

For sure shifting is MUCH simpler than addition. For shifting there is much less logic from FF (flip flop) to FF. For addition, carry has to be propagated from the LSB bit to the MSB bit, which means log2(N) levels of logic (N is the top value that counter would reach).
On the other hand, shift register would use N FFs, while adder would only use log2(N) FFs.
So there is a performance / area trade off which also heavily depends on N. Some 'independent' info about adder:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29
Couldn't find similar article for shifting, but once you understand adder, shifter should be obvious.

This might be important when you are designing the state machine in RTL. But the code you presented has actually nothing to do with the above. This 'for' loop in verilog means all the 'work' will be done in single cycle. So there will actually be N logics. This loop has nothing to do with implementation. It might even only confuse verilog compiler to spit out something strange and affect simulation (where CPU cycles does matter and above answers would be valid). Someone with more experience with tools could comment on that.

Comment: I was fairly sure that the original poster was asking if the C version of it was useful, given the "inspired by hardware design" wording (implying it's not hardware design) and the comment about embedded systems.  But you're right, it's worth clarifying.

Comment: Right, I thought others didn't, but looks like I didn't read the question careful enough...

Comment: @Stefan
I just did a course at university called 'High-Performance Computations with FPGA'. But I haven't had any previous knowledge on FPGAs or Electronic design or Verilog. I was just curious. It covered some interesting stuff like adder, multiplier, divider, exponentiation circuits. Probably trivial for an electrical engineer. 
At first when I had to count something I just created a **reg [n:0] cnt** and I incremented that like **cnt<=cnt+1**. For me it wasn't obvious that **+** is invoking an adder circuit. Then I learned this shift register thing, thats where the idea came from.

Answer (score 2):

(As per Stefan's answer, I'm assuming you're asking about the C version inspired by the Verilog version, not about doing this in Verilog.)

On many architectures, this is actually worse, because the bit shift takes an extra instruction while the addition for the loop variable is completely free.

Completely?

Yes.  Because there are, on many architectures, single instructions that decrement a counter and branch if it is nonzero -- and these instructions take just as much time as any other compare-and-branch instruction.  Whereas, if you're doing a shift, that takes an extra instruction cycle.  It's even worse if your platform doesn't have a "compare equal and branch" instruction -- and not all of them do; some make you subtract and compare to zero in two instructions.

Even on a RISC platform with no decrement-compare-branch instruction, the countdown loop is probably faster because you can simply subtract (one instruction) and use the branch-if-nonzero instruction -- whereas, in your loop, you need a shift (one instruction) and a bitwise-and (one instruction) before the branch-if-zero.  And that's assuming you even have a branch-if-zero.

Moreover, for a simple `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)` loop, it's trivial for the compiler to convert it to a "count down to 0" loop if that's faster -- you rarely need to even do that bit of cleverness yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In a real CPU, addition is one of the fastest things you can do; a bitshift is *not* any faster. And you will make it harder for the compiler to optimize efficiently.

Comment: Also _much_ harder to read and understand, which is the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Faster? Are you sure about that? At least on the MIPS architecture, a bit shift takes exactly as long as an addition. I would be surprised if this wasn't true of the most common consumer-oriented processor architectures as well.

Besides, as Oleksi notes, this is rather hard to read. Probably not worth a nonexistant speed gain.

Answer (score 1):

Increment is a very special case of addition. In most processors and certainly most RISC processors a shift and an increment will be identical in execution time.  In fact in most architectures addition will take no longer either.

When you keep your loop code idiomatic, the optimiser is likley to simply unroll the loop and render it faster in any case.  If you make the loop mechanism "unusual" the optimiser may be unable to optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to always loop a specific number of times > 0 and minimize loop overhead, then I think this will be the "best":

```
unsigned i = 16;

do {
// do something here
} while (--i);



You might get the same result with:

unsigned i = 0x8000;

do {
// do something here
} while (i>>=1);
```

At that point you would have to look at the assembly.

Comment: The reason that the first version is faster is that many architectures have a single instruction for decrement and branch if not zero.